# Move contact from Phone to SD card programmatically by Android

Tags: android, contacts, sd-card

How to move a particular contact from Phone or SIM to SD Card programmatically by Android ?
I wanted to do programmatically by android in my applicaiton. Not all contacts, only contacts I select. I have already written code for selecting a contact. I want to move this contact to SD card. 
Please help